# Conditioning a Brownian Bridge

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Brownian Bridge:

Consider the standard Brownian $X(t)$ motion conditioned to land at $b$ at time $1$. This means that for every trajectory {$(t,X(t)), 0 \leq t \leq 1$} of this process, its initial point $(0,X(0)) = (0,0)$ is connected to its terminal point $(1,X(1)) = (1,b)$. This makes it a bridge, since all trajectories of the Brownian motion are continuous functions of time.

How would I go about finding the density of this process, i.e.
$f_{t|1} (x|b)=\dfrac{f_{t,1}(x,b)}{f_{1}(b)}$

Thanks!